# COBOL - What does this mean?

Tags: mainframe

I have been assigned to retire and replace a couple COBOL programs.  I don't know COBOL and have been figuring it out on the fly as to what the program is doing.  Here is a section I don't understand

```
 DTECON1,(INIT=C'F49E')                    /*LAST WORKDAY,PREV MONTH*/
 DTELAST,REDEFINES,DTECON1=(15,6)                           /*YYMMDD*/
 DTECCYM,REDEFINES,DTECON1=(13,6)                           /*CCYYMM*/
 DTEYYMM,REDEFINES,DTECON1=(15,4)
  C=(55,4:6,Y2CH,LT,DTECCYM,CH,OR,
55,1,CH,EQ,C' ',OR,                   /*DRAFT ISSUE DTE 55-60  */
56,1,CH,EQ,C' ',OR,
57,1,CH,EQ,C' ',OR,
58,1,CH,EQ,C' ',OR,
59,1,CH,EQ,C' ',OR,
60,1,CH,EQ,C' ')
 M=(DTELAST,CH,TO,55,6,CH)    /*SET TO LAST DAY OF PROCESSING MONTH*/
NOWRITE
```

I know the numbers are the byte location on the file. Y2CH is a home built function to check for Y2K. I understand the DTELAST, DTECCYM, DTEYYMM part.  What I am stuggling with is `CH`, `OR`, `EQ`, `4:6`.

Also I assume C= and M= are variables.  Are those correct assumptions?

Comment: This is not COBOL.

Comment: What language is it?  JCL?  - I have no mainframe experience.

Comment: This is not JCL.

Comment: You seem to indicate you encountered this as a section of a COBOL program, please show us the surrounding code so we have some context.

Comment: It looks like DFSORT statements. My guess would be that "55,1,CH,EQ,C' '" means look at the field at position 55 with length 1. Interpret it as a character field. Check if it is equal to a space.

Comment: @staples part of your question includes "***I don't know COBOL***" ... So what makes you think it is ... COBOL? How does the very first line of this "thing" look like? Does it start with "IDENTIFICATION ...""? If it is a COBOL pgm, then it better should include that as the very first line of it (= lesson  1 in getting started with COBOL) ...